# Failed to handle method call flutter using open_file packages

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, flutter-dependencies

i am trying to use pdf in my project but getting error. I followed the instructions on the pdf packages.

this is my error

```
I/flutter (15157): Helvetica has no Unicode support see https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/wiki/Fonts-Management
E/MethodChannel#open_file(15157): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#open_file(15157): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.poin_of_sales/app_flutter/sample.pdf
```

This is my code to create pdf and open pdf file

```
class PdfGenerator {
  static void getPdf() async {
    final pdf = pw.Document();
    var data = await rootBundle.load("assets/open-sans.ttf");
    var myFont = Font.ttf(data);
    var myStyle = TextStyle(font: myFont);

    pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return <pw.Widget>[
            pw.Header(
                level: 0,
                child: pw.Text("Demo Sample First Header",
                    style: myStyle)),
            pw.Paragraph(
                text:
                    "Some Text.",
                style: myStyle),
            pw.Header(
                level: 1, child: pw.Text("Second Header", style: myStyle)),
            pw.Paragraph(
                text:
                    "Some Text.",
                style: myStyle),
          ]; // Center
        }));
    
    Uint8List bytes = await pdf.save();
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File('${dir.path}/sample.pdf');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    await OpenFile.open(file.path);
  }
}
```

Comment: use try{}catch (error){} on await OpenFile.open(file.path); to see if it catches the error.